# ThemeData inheritTheme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true) error

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter 2.0.1
Dart 2.12

I have problem with building iOS app on simulator. (iOS 14.4) Build stops and throw error listed below:

```
 ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    ../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.4.0/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:215:48: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
        ThemeData inheritTheme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

I read that Theme.of was replaced by InheritedTheme/or InheritTheme, however when I peek problem I got the message that listed files do not exists (example below)

```
Unable to open 'theme.dart': Unable to read file '/Users/userName/hdk/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart' 
(Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/Users/userName/hdk/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart').
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at /Users/paweljagla/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (17 hours ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/paweljagla/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max (mobile) • 87DDB2A3-2284-4D85-A835-FE842809E6E9 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4
      (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192
```

I've try: clean, update flutter, update-packages, reinstall flutter and nothing works. How to get rid of this error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is very frequently in flutter (since newest and oldest) I use flutter 2.0.2 and still have the same issue, but normally is not from flutter, on the contrary it is from the package or lib, sometimes it is very easy to solve, and you have two options:

1. Update the package, or
2. Editing directly the package code, to solve it

   a) Go to the package directory

   b) Open the file indicate in the error

   c) And remove the code causing the error

   d) Save and close the file, thats it.

For example, i have the same issue with this package: **flutter_cupertino_date_picker** and I edit the source code to remove the error,

a) package directory:

```
C:/silex/SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter-cupertino-date-picker-38630701b92a4fd0b753f9ab38b3581a5645a629/lib/src/
```

b) file:

```
date_picker.dart
```

c) removed: 'shadowThemeOnly: true'

```
theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
```

d) saved:

```
theme: Theme.of(context).
```

Another example: [DiagnosticableMixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611380/getting-error-diagnosticablemixin-after-update-flutter-sdk-2-0)

It is not always easy to find the error, but it almost always works, I hope it helps, because this is the best way to temporarily fix these types of errors until the package is updated. Regards!.