# Getting error DiagnosticableMixin after Update flutter SDK 2.0

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

After Update flutter SDK 2.0 i am getting below error.

../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cupertino_date_picker-1.0.26+2/lib/src/date_picker_theme.dart:23:32: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class DateTimePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cupertino_date_picker-1.0.26+2/lib/src/date_picker_theme.dart:23:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class DateTimePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {
^
../../SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cupertino_date_picker-1.0.26+2/lib/src/date_picker.dart:103:34: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {

Answer (score 3):

check  flutter_cupertino_date_picker lib.  date_picker_theme.dart file  have Below Code.

```
 class DateTimePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {
  }
```

In Flutter 2.0 version they remove falvor DiagnosticableMixin. so remove DiagnosticableMixin  with Diagnosticable.  change  date_picker_theme.dart file as per below code.

```
  class DateTimePickerTheme with Diagnosticable {
  }
```